# Number of twisted primes less than 20,000

Tags: prime-numbers

We call number $N$ a twisted prime if we turn all the 6-es in 9s and all the 9s in 6-es and it remains a prime(If it has no 6-es or 9s it is not twisted). How many twisted primes there are? ($N \leq 20000$)

Source: School friend.
Is there a way to really calculate it except counting to 20000?

Comment: It would seem that this question is about as hard to answer as the question of how many primes in general there are less than 20,000. Just my thought.

Comment: For $N\le 20000$, how many primes are there having $6$ or $9$ as digits?  Do we count a prime as "vacuously twisted" if it has no $6$ or $9$ digits?  What happens when the question is changed to consider "mirror primes" as those primes having $2$ or $5$ as digits, and those digits are "mirrored" so that $2$ becomes $5$ and $5$ becomes $2$?

Comment: The most efficient way is to use the list of $2262$ precalculated primes $\le 20000$. Then observe, that the $6$ cannot be the last digit. Most primes are not twisted, anyway. The first one is $67$ with $97$.

Comment: There is no useful way other than counting because a number and its twisted image are more or less unrelated in any useful regard.

Comment: Oneliner in mathematica: Length[Select[Range[20000], 
  PrimeQ[#] && 
    PrimeQ[FromDigits[IntegerDigits[#] /. {6 -> 9, 9 -> 6}]] &]]

Answer (score 1):

There are 1224 twisted primes below 20000.
There are 89372 twisted  primes below $10^7$.
In PARI/GP this helps

```
twist(d)=if(d==9 || d==6, 15-d,d)
tw(n)=if(n<10,twist(n),tw(n\10)*10+twist(n%10))
ac=0;forprime(p=2,20000,q=tw(p);if(q!=p&&isprime(tw(p)),ac++));ac
```

Comment: Oops, I had to edit cause I had considered primes without any 6 or 9 vacuously twisted at first

Comment: So , i will answer my friend in code.

Comment: While I can reproduce your result for $20000$ I get $222579$ for $10^7$.